# Curl: Invalid JSON

Tags: json, curl

I'm trying to use the sendgrid curl for adding a new contact.

This is what I got

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer myAPIKEY' \
  --data '{"contacts":[{"email":"mymail@icloud.com","first_name":"Karel","last_name":"Deb"}]}’
```

But it returns this

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "",
      "message": "invalid JSON"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your json ends with `\`` instead of `'`. I think that is what is causing the error.

Comment: @Yuvraj No, you copied it wrong. It is wrong because he is not passing the content type header

Comment: `'` This is a quote. `’` This is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying that the body is of type JSON. you need to add `--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \` to your request.

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer myAPIKEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"contacts":[{"email":"mymail@icloud.com","first_name":"Karel","last_name":"Deb"}]}’
```